# Remove string from QStringList if string value is part of other string

Tags: string, qt

I want to remove a string from a QStringList (*folders* in the code below) if it is included in another string from the same list.

Example:  "**/tmp/a** /tmp/b **/tmp/a/aa** /tmp/c **/tmp/a/aa/aaa** /tmp/d"

I want to remove the first and third string as they are included in the fifth.
I know how to do it with grep in bash, but how would I do it with Qt?

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButtonSourceFolders_clicked()
{
    QString startDir = lineEditStartFolder->text();
    QFileDialog* folderDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
    folderDialog->setDirectory(lineEditStartFolder->text());
    folderDialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
    folderDialog->setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, true);
    folderDialog->setOption(QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly, true);
    folderDialog->setOption(QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks, true);
    QListView *folderList = folderDialog->findChild<QListView*>("listView");
    if (folderList) {
        folderList->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
    }
    QTreeView *folderTree = folderDialog->findChild<QTreeView*>();
    if (folderTree) {
        folderTree->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
    }

    folderDialog->exec();
    QStringList folders = folderDialog->selectedFiles();
    if (!folders.isEmpty())
            listWidget->addItems(folders);
}
```

The complete code is available at https://github.com/FluxFlux/qdir2mod

Comment: How is third "included" in another folder? Your task description is inaccurate, but even then: what is the _real_ use case?

Comment: Check QStringList::filter(const QString & str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive) Also you can use regex.

Comment: @Final Contest: Thanks for the hint. I've fixed the 'third' folder. The final application will be used to merge folders into a squashfs based file. I have added the url to the conmplete code at github.

Comment: Does this algorithm have to perform well? How many folders do you have in worst case? The slowest algorithm is O(n^2), otherwise sorting may speed it up if it is not yet sorted. You could also build a Trie and leave the leaf nodes.

Comment: @Final Contest: I will have an estimated max count of folders <= 20

Comment: @Final Contest: Gone to work at clients side now ;)

Comment: In that case, I would write an embedded for loop to get each folder and then check if anything else contains that, but you need to cautious about spaces, etc, in the path... how will you handle that? You currently do not seem to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, since the maximum number of directories is 20, I would not bother optimizing the algorithm, hence I would just go with the simplest:

```
QStringList folders = folderDialog->selectedFiles();
QStringList outputFolders = folders;
foreach (const QString &folder, folders) {
    foreach (const QString &f, folders) {
        if (f.contains(folder))
            outputFolders.removeOne(folder);
    }
}
```

You could also avoid the temporary copy, but then again, it would make the code more complex which is not worth for 20 "folders".

Also, please note that "folder" is a GUI term. What you are referring to is files and directories which is more universal. It is better to use the proper term and not get stuck with GUI terms, only.

Comment: `removeOne`and `contains` are probably O(n), so your code would be O(n^3), which seems bad even for just 20 items, and as you don't handle the case where `f==folder`, the list will always be empty.

Comment: @alexisdm: Thanks for your valuable comment. You are right!

Comment: @Final contest: Thanks a bunch for your answer! With a slight modification I've solved my problem. :D

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification I've solved the problem:

```
QStringList folders = folderDialog->selectedFiles();
QStringList outputFolders = folders;
foreach (const QString &folder, folders) {
    foreach (const QString &f, folders) {
        const QString &cfolder = (folder + "/");
        if (f.contains(cfolder))
            outputFolders.removeOne(folder);
    }
}
if (!outputFolders.isEmpty())
        listWidget->addItems(outputFolders);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `contains` for directories but `startsWith` (for instane, the string `/tmp/tmp/a/b` contains `/tmp/a` which is not what you want).

Comment: @alexisdm: Thanks again for the next valuable comment. :D